# Getting the first and second element from a 3 tuple in a list - Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

So I am passing a 3 tuple list into this function and want to return the first and third element of that tuple, why doesn't the code here work?

```
remove :: (a, b, c) -> (a,c)
remove (x, _, y) = (x,y)
```

The error I get is

```
*** Expression     : remove (sortScore b h)
*** Term           : sortScore b h
*** Type           : [(Val,Int,End)]
*** Does not match : (a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sortScore` is returning a list of 3-tuples, but `remove` only accepts one.

You can use `map` to apply `remove` to each element returned from `sortScore`

```
map remove (sortScore b h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map` to transform each tuple in list `sortScore b h`:

```
map remove $ sortScore b h
```

You can't apply `remove` just to `sortScore b h` because the last one is a list but `remove` works on tuples.

Comment: Okay, I meant to say first and third, let me edit it